# DeflateStream.Read always returns zero

Tags: .net, compression, deflate

I have a perfectly valid zip file, which contains exactly one packed file, that can be decompressed via external utilities, and it doesn't let anything useful out of DeflateStream. I've removed first two bytes prefix ("50h 4Bh", having those always yields "Block length does not match with its complement" exception), but then no progress - unzipped[] always contains zeroes and Read also returns 0.

```
byte[] zipped = new byte[] { 0x03, 0x04, 0x14, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0xe4, 0x6e, 0x89, 0x4a, 0x1d, 0x42, 0x8f, 0xb7, 0x1d, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x44, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x63, 0x64, 0x60, 0x60, 0xa8, 0xd7, 0x0b, 0x62, 0x60, 0xa8, 0x65, 0xc4, 0x8e, 0x41, 0x0a, 0x18, 0x18, 0xeb, 0x41, 0x14, 0xa3, 0x08, 0x03, 0x8c, 0x0f, 0x27, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x50, 0x4b, 0x01, 0x02, 0x14, 0x00, 0x14, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0xe4, 0x6e, 0x89, 0x4a, 0x1d, 0x42, 0x8f, 0xb7, 0x1d, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x44, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x50, 0x4b, 0x05, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x2f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
MemoryStream zipstream = new MemoryStream(zipped);
byte[] unzipped = new byte[1024];
using (MemoryStream unzipstream = new MemoryStream(unzipped))
{
    using (DeflateStream worker = new DeflateStream(zipstream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        try
        {
            int length = worker.Read(unzipped, 0, 1024);

            //worker.CopyTo(unzipstream);
            //Console.Write(unzipstream.Length);
            //int length = unzipstream.Read(unzipped,0,1024);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a zip file, not a zlib stream. Use the `ZipFile` class.

Comment: Thank you, that would work.  
  
    `ZipArchive ziparc = ZipFile.Open(openFileDialog1.FileName, ZipArchiveMode.Read);
    DeflateStream defstream0 = (DeflateStream)ziparc.Entries[0].Open();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    defstream0.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);`   

But I should have described my situation better. I'm trying to avoid disk operations, since I receive this archive as a byte[].

Comment: You can use `ZipInputStream` in that case which can work on an in-memory array that you wrap in a `ByteArrayInputStream`. @ZuOverture